# Encode/decode a string for it to pass umlauts in filenames?

Tags: php, utf-8, diacritics

I have a script that takes the argument `g`. After that a relative filename is expected.
So I have a https://server.com/index.php?g=test/test.php. I know what you say, but this is not about security.

Now I want to use this script from within the server. I am german so my files sometimes have umlauts.

When using `shell_exec('wget --user username --password pw -qO- --no-check-certificate https://server.com/index.php?g=test/test%F6.jpg &> /dev/null');` the script gets the filename properly.

But when trying to run it from within, ie

```
$_GET['g'] = 'test/test%F6.jpg';
include('index.php');
```

or

```
$_GET['g'] = 'test/testö.jpg';
include('index.php');
```

or

```
$_GET['g'] = utf8_decode('test/testö.jpg');
include('index.php');
```

or

```
$_GET['g'] = utf8_encode('test/testö.jpg');
include('index.php');
```

it never finds the file.

How do I have to encode/decode the $_GET['g'] string for it to pass umlauts successfully?

EDIT:  I found it works by changing the encoding of my test file to ansi. In the main script it works. So it was just the formatting of the script file itself to ansi.

Comment: If you execute the command as `test%F6`, which is literally *"percent sign eff six"*, then `$_GET['g'] = 'test/test%F6.jpg'` should work just fine. Anything else you don't typically want to deal with anyway; handling non-ASCII filenames from PHP is somewhere between a giant headache and impossible.

Comment: I found it works by changing the encoding of my test file to ansi. In the main script it works. So it was just the formatting of the script file itself to ansi.